# Ruby has Seemingly Erratic Results from 23+9.23 = 32.230000000000004

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive very interesting and seemingly erratic results in irb for Ruby. What is going on?

This is correct!

```
>> 23+9.22 
=> 32.22
```

This is not!

```
>> 23+9.23 
=> 32.230000000000004
```

Where are all the trailing zeroes coming from?  What is going on?

Comment: That's what you get for dealing with floats. It's the same in e.g. Python.

Comment: It's the same in most languages.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: I thought that it's been a while since this perennial favourite came up..

Comment: Variations on this question have been asked many times before.  In fact, there is a website dedicated to answering this question: [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
puts "%.30f" % 9.23
#=> 9.230000000000000426325641456060
```

Because of the difference between base-2 (computer internal representation of numbers) and base-10 (what you are used to dealing with and are typing into your text editor or IRB), you cannot represent 9.23 *exactly* as a floating point value. This is not specific to Ruby, but present in nearly every programming language.

For example, 9.23 is represented internally as a sum of powers of two, something like:

```
01001.00111010111...
||||| ||||||||||+-> 1 * 1/2048 \            
||||| |||||||||+--> 1 * 1/1024  \          
||||| ||||||||+---> 1 * 1/512    \        
||||| |||||||+----> 0 * 1/256     \       
||||| ||||||+-----> 1 * 1/128      \      
||||| |||||+------> 0 * 1/64         fraction = 0.22998046875
||||| ||||+-------> 1 * 1/32       /     
||||| |||+--------> 1 * 1/16      /      
||||| ||+---------> 1 * 1/8      /      
||||| |+----------> 0 * 1/4     /       
||||| +-----------> 0 * 1/2    /        
|||||  
||||+-------------> 1 * 1      \
|||+--------------> 0 * 2       \  
||+---------------> 0 * 4         integer = 9
|+----------------> 1 * 8       /
+-----------------> 0 * 16     /
```

For more information, go read *[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)* and the [IEEE 754 description on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers).

Your workarounds, when precision is important (such as currency) are to:

1. Keep track of the smallest available unit for your calculations (e.g. pennies) and only convert to decimal for display. For example:

   ```ruby
   result = 2300 + 923          # $23.00 + $9.23
   puts "%.2f" % (result/100.0) # Ensure output rounded to two decimal places
   #=> 32.23
   ```
2. Use a library like [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to keep track of exact precision for you, and set your database to use a fixed-precision data type like [DECIMAL or NUMERIC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).
3. Accept that the numeric values will usually be "close enough", and always use a formatting option when displaying them to the user, e.g.

   ```ruby
   result = 23 + 9.27    #=> 32.269999999999996
   puts "%g" % result    #=> 32.27
   puts "%.3f" % result  #=> 32.270
   puts "%.1f" % result  #=> 32.3
   ```

Comment: There should be a hat awarded on SO whenever someone uses a link to WECSSKAFPA. I have personally pointed people at it about 100 times.  I can always use moar hatz.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Ruby. This is a know problem of representation of floating point numbers in computers.

If you are doing financial or monetary processing, then you want to stay away from floating point numbers to represent your amounts.